# Cannot insert data into multiple databases Codeigniter (MongoDB and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, json, mongodb, codeigniter

I am developing a rest api server with reference to https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver. I am using Mongo and Mysql to save the api responses. My controller saves webhooks endpoint response. I can save data to Mongo but MYSQL is not working. Please advice.

My Controller - Hooks.php

```
  public function opened_post() {

//        $_POST = $this->request->body;

        //Get the message id
        if(!$mid = $this->input->post('message-id')) $this->response(array("status" => true));

        //Parse message ID
        $mid = explode("@", $mid, 2)[0];

        //Update the record
         $this->mail_store->mid($mid)->data(array('opened' => true))->update();


  $this->load->model('message_store');
  $this->messages_store->add();

        $this->response(array("status" => "success"));
    }
```

My Model - Message_store.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Message_store extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();

    }

    /**
     * Store message into queue
     */
    public function add($event, $data, $token) {

        {

        $store = array('event' => 'HOOK', 'data' => 'Grap', 'token' => 'ABC12345');

          $this->db->insert($store->hooks, $store);
        }

        //Clear
        $this->clear_();
    }


}


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developed a seperate PHP file that asks the Restserver to save the the webhooks in both Mongo and MYSQL.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**